# Can i use pure HTML side by side with Thyme Leaf template engine in a spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot

I haven't tried this before but i wanted to know before i started the journey if i can use pure html alongside thymeleaf in a springboot application. I am trying to achieve sending HTML mail through the use of Thyme leaf, while using the pure HTML as my casual view for my controllers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @eshiett1995 help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, thyme leaf is pure html itself. Now the problem is how to configure it.